# APNS notification fails to be delivered (error code 8)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

When I try to execute an apple push notification on the server I get the following error:

```
com.notnoop.exceptions.ApnsDeliveryErrorException: Failed to deliver notification with error code 8
```

My server is a Java application. It is strange that the same server WAR file works OK locally (notifications are sent), but it does not work (with error above) when I deploy it to remote server (RedHat openshift.com).

Here is what I do:

1. In Xcode I archive my application and export it for Ad Hoc
   distribution using Distribution Provisioning profile. The profile
   contains "aps-environment production" entitlement.
2. In Apple
   Developer center, I download the APNs production iOS certificate,
   import it in my iMac Keychain and export a p12 file.
3. I deploy the
   .p12 file to my server, where I use
   https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns library to execute apple push
   notifications. The library is initialized like this:

**APNS.newService().withCert(certificateInputStream,"*password*").withProductionDestination().withDelegate(this).build();**

4. When run, the client application successfully registeres for push
   notifications and receives a token.
5. When the server tries to
   execute a push notification, an exception is thrown:
   com.notnoop.exceptions.ApnsDeliveryErrorException: Failed to deliver
   notification with error code 8

Can you help? What could be the reason that the same setup works on a local but fail on a remote server?

Comment: 8 means invalid device token. Perhaps you tried to push a sandbox device token to the production push env or vice versa.

Comment: Hi Eran, the device token has been obtained by the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken callback in my App Delegate and the application is signed with a distr. provisioning profile containing the aps production environment entitlement. Is there something I can do in order to verify if a device token is for production environment? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared to be another error. The server contained old deployment (war) file, which was still pointing to the sandbox APNS environment. After I redeployed manually, the problem is gone.

Comment: Could you accept your answer? You may need to wait for more reputation.